In what order should I read Emily Wilson's translations of Homer?
Emily Wilson's translation of the Iliad was published in 2023, joining her translation of the Odyssey from 2018. I have recently procured copies of said translations with the intent to read them in the coming year. In what order should I read them?
Since the action of the Iliad is prior to that of the Odyssey, I've habitually worked my way through previous translations in that order. Robert Fagles's and Stanley Lombardo's translations of each of those works also appeared in that order. E. V. Rieu's Penguin Classics versions, however, reversed this, with the Odyssey having a copyright date of 1946 and the Iliad, 1950. For technical reasons I was unable to read them when they first appeared; when I did eventually read them I began with the Iliad.
Does it make sense to read Wilson's Odyssey first, since she translated that one first? Or would it be preferable to read her Iliad first, since the events of the Odyssey presuppose those of the Iliad? The answers to an earlier, related question Can the Odyssey be consumed independently of the Iliad? have argued that in general, the reading order makes no difference. But in this specific case, it's possible that Wilson's later translation relies on a knowledge of her earlier. For example, if some language or metaphor in her Iliad echoes that in her Odyssey, a reader unfamiliar with her earlier translation might miss out on the nuances of her meaning. So to narrow down the question to these particular translations, thereby (hopefully) differentiating it from the previous one linked above: Does Wilson's translation of the Iliad presuppose familiarity with her prior translation of the Odyssey? Or at least, would a reader unfamiliar with Wilson's Odyssey miss some of the finer details of her Iliad?

I have read both translations and the answer, as far as I can tell, is "no", but it is impossible to prove a negative (there could be something I missed) so I see no way to write an answer, sorry!

@GarethRees I thought if anybody could answer, you could! I'd happily accept an answer that says what order you read the texts in, and if you read the Odyssey first and the Iliad later, something to the effect that nothing in the latter translation specifically called to mind something in the former.

Many phrases in each work call to mind corresponding phrases in the other—that's just the nature of Homeric poetry. For example, Wilson translates πολύμητις Ὀδυσσεύς as "cunning Odysseus", and Γερήνιος ἱππότα Νέστωρ as "Gerenian Nestor, lord of horses", and ἠριγένεια Ἠώς as "newborn Dawn" in both works. But there's no reason (as far as I can see) to prefer to first encounter these epithets in one work or the other.

Yes, but those are not specific to Wilson. That is, her choice of English equivalents certainly is distinctive ("cunning" rather than, say, "resourceful" for Odysseus), but its recurrence is not a deliberate poetic strategy on her part. What I was wondering about is more something like how reading Paradise Regained without having first read Paradise Lost would diminish one's understanding of what Milton is doing with Satan and Jesus, not in terms of knowing the back story, but in terms of their specific characterization in poetic terms. (contd.)

It seems that by putting together your previous two comments, you'd already have an answer. Care to do so?
